# Download several excel files with one click

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have several php files which contain different queries to a postgresql database. There about sixteen of these files. Each of these files returns a different set of data based on the query within the file. After a query is made, you can download the file and the download is into an excel file. 
My question is how can i trigger a download in php such that i can have just one link and upon clicking it, all these sixteen files are downloaded at once. I dont want to download each file on its on. Or better still i could have checkboxes and i select the files i would like to download. I hope my question is clear enough.

For example i have this file named export_a.php with this code

```
<?php require_once('connections/pgconn.php');


function cleanData(&$str)
{
$str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
$str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
}

// filename for download
$filename = "eastafrica_revenue_daily" . date('Ymd') . ".xls";

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

$flag = false;
$result = pg_query("SELECT to_char (a.CALLDATE,'yyyymmdd') as transdate,
    sum(a.alltaxcost::integer) AS revenue,
     COUNT (DISTINCT a.IDENTIFIANT) AS distinct_callers,
a.zoneiddest as country_code,b.country
FROM cdr_data a,  COUNTRY_CODES b
WHERE  a.CALLSUBCLASS = '002'
     AND a.CALLCLASS = '008'
and a.zoneiddest::integer > 0
AND SUBSTR (a.CALLEDNUMBER, 1, 2) NOT IN
('77', '78', '75', '70', '71', '41', '31', '39', '76','79')
and  substr(a.zoneiddest,1,3) in ('254','255','211','257','250')
and trim(a.zoneiddest)  = trim(b.country_code)
GROUP BY to_char (a.CALLDATE,'yyyymmdd') ,a.zoneiddest,b.country
ORDER BY 1") or die('Query failed!');

while(false !== ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result))) {
if(!$flag) {
  // display field/column names as first row
  echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
  $flag = true;
}
array_walk($row, 'cleanData');
echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
}
exit;
?>
```

Then i have another file say export_b.php with another query. When a link is clicked on a certain page say a.php where this query is made, it exports to excel. 
My question is how can i trigger a download in php such that i can have just one link and upon clicking it, all these sixteen files are downloaded at once. I dont want to download each file on its on. Or better still i could have checkboxes and i select the files i would like to download.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Your question is clear, but overly broad. You seem to need a tutorial, rather than an answer to a specific problem.

Comment: well i have read about phpexcel. Seems to have too much from what i need. Basically if i may rephrase, i need a way in which with a click of a button or a link a function is triggered such that the the files which contain the queries are all downloaded at a go. Not a tutorial as such but point me in the right direction to solve my problem in the shortest time and yet i learn too

Comment: you have to run each query one by one and create excel on server and download it in zip file

Comment: So your suggesting that When each query is made, its first stored on the server then they are all zipped and the download is triggered

Comment: First point to note is that you're writing HTML here, with just a link to the Excel file export..... does the code in export_eard.php create the Excel file (it looks as though it should) in which case you could perhaps show us that

Comment: Yes i have placed it here in the edit.

Comment: OK, so you're creating tab-separated value files rather than Excel files; in that case.... create each file for each query, and then zip them together for download

Comment: the files are already created... my question is how do i zip them before they are downloaded? What do i have to add to my current code that will help me  achieve this. A sample could be helpful

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download Excel files, why not download a single Excel file containing 16 worksheets (one for each of your datasets);

Alternatively zip all the files together, and download the zip

Comment: Yes and how would i go about that? How do i aggregate all the different files that contain the different queries and also each file exports the query to excel into one file?

Comment: Without knowing how you're doing your queries now, it's almost impossible to say how to aggregate them; your question is pretty vague, so all I can offer is suggestions rather than code an answer for you.... but running each query individually and writing to the excel worksheet individually, or to file individually; then saving to Excel or zipping

Comment: Let me edit my question and add some code snippets to make more clear.

Comment: This is the best answer you can get to your question, as it is now. Go try these suggestions, and return with some code (if you will still have problems).